# Tree data structure in php

Tags: php, data-structures, hierarchical-data

in my application user starts a new tree or get added under a child-user and keep on adding users in branches in such a way-
`>`there are 10 level of tree type structure.
`>`root node contain `1` user and each node(user) can have **max** `5` child-user in this way tree  will be like `level 0 = 1 user` ,
`level 1 = 5 user`,
 `level 2 = 25 user` ,
`level 3 = 125 user` and so on.

I created one MySQL table having columns like-

`User_id` , `level`, `super_id`, `child1_id`, `child2_id`, `child3_id`, `child4_id`, `child5_id`

**my question is How can I get all child-user(`child to child also`) of a particular user at any level** do I need to add some more columns in my table??

Answer (score 4):

You might find it interesting to read my presentation from last week's PHP TEK-X conference:

### [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

This talk describes alternative solutions in SQL, including:

- Adjacency List
- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

Also see my answer to this Stack Overflow question: [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Nested Sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

In PHP, you could use [Doctrine Nested Sets](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/behaviors:core-behaviors:nestedset), that will make your life much easier.

Comment: -1 for a solution that requires not only a very specific and complex framework but also is an OO only approach, and provides no explanation of how it works. While this toolkit may have factory support for rebuiding trees rather than a straight ORM (which is really inefficient) - you don't say which is the case.

Answer (score -2):

This is the complete code i used to build a binary tree datastructure and its corresponding operations:

```
<?php
class Node
{
 public $data;
 public $leftChild;
 public $rightChild;

 public function __construct($data)
  {
   $this->data=$data;
   $this->leftChild=null;
   $this->rightChild=null;
  }
 public function disp_data()
  {
   echo $this->data;
  }


}//end class Node
class BinaryTree
{
 public $root;
 //public $s;
 public function __construct()
  {
   $this->root=null;
   //$this->s=file_get_contents('store');

  }
//function to display the tree
  public function display()
  {
   $this->display_tree($this->root);

  }
  public function display_tree($local_root)
  {

   if($local_root==null) 
     return;
    $this->display_tree($local_root->leftChild);
    echo $local_root->data."<br/>";
    $this->display_tree($local_root->rightChild);

  } 
// function to insert a new node
  public function insert($key)
   {
    $newnode=new Node($key);
      if($this->root==null)
        {
         $this->root=$newnode;
         return;
        }
      else
        {
         $parent=$this->root;
         $current=$this->root;
           while(true)
             {
               $parent=$current;
                 //$this->find_order($key,$current->data);
                if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
                  {
                      $current=$current->leftChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->leftChild=$newnode;
                          return;
                         }//end if2
                  }//end if1 
                else
                  {
                      $current=$current->rightChild;
                       if($current==null)
                         {
                          $parent->rightChild=$newnode;
                          return;  
                         } //end if1                       
                  } //end else
             }//end while loop 
        }//end else

   } //end insert function

//function to search a particular Node
 public function find($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
            if($key==$this->find_order($key,$current->data))
              {
                $current=$current->leftChild;
              }
            else
              {
                $current=$current->rightChild;
              }
            if($current==null)
              return(null);

          }
         return($current->data); 
  }// end the function to search
 public function delete1($key)
  {
    $current=$this->root;
    $parent=$this->root;

    $isLeftChild=true;
     while($current->data!=$key)
          {
           $parent=$current;
           if($key==($this->find_order($key,$current->data)))
             {
              $current=$current->leftChild;
              $isLeftChild=true;
             }   
           else
             {
              $current=$current->rightChild;
              $isLeftChild=false;   
             } 
            if($current==null)
              return(null);
          }//end while loop 

      echo "<br/><br/>Node to delete:".$current->data;
     //to delete a leaf node 
     if($current->leftChild==null&&$current->rightChild==null)
       {
           if($current==$this->root)
              $this->root=null;  
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=null;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=null;
           }
         return($current);       
       }//end if1
     //to delete a node having a leftChild 
   else if($current->rightChild==null)
       {
          if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->leftChild;
          else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
           }
          else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->leftChild;
           }   
          return($current);
       }//end else if1
    //to delete a node having a rightChild
   else if($current->leftChild==null)
       {
         if($current==$this->root)
           $this->root=$current->rightChild;
         else if($isLeftChild==true)
           {
            $parent->leftChild=$current->rightChild;
           }  
         else
           {
            $parent->rightChild=$current->rightChild; 
           }  
           return($current);
       }  
   //to delete a node having both childs
    else
       {
        $successor=$this->get_successor($current);
        if($current==$this->root)
          {
            $this->root=$successor; 

          }
        else if($isLeftChild==true)
          {
           $parent->leftChild=$successor;
          }
        else
          {
           $parent->rightChild=$successor;
          }     
         $successor->leftChild=$current->leftChild;
        return($current);
       }   


  }//end the function to delete a node
//Function to find the successor node
 public function get_successor($delNode)
  {
   $succParent=$delNode;
   $successor=$delNode;
   $temp=$delNode->rightChild;
    while($temp!=null)
         {
          $succParent=$successor;
          $successor=$temp;
          $temp=$temp->leftChild;
         }
   if($successor!=$delNode->rightChild)
     {
      $succParent->leftChild=$successor->rightChild;
      $successor->rightChild=$delNode->rightChild;
     }
  return($successor);
  }
//function to find the order of two strings
 public function find_order($str1,$str2)
  {
     $str1=strtolower($str1);
     $str2=strtolower($str2);
     $i=0;
     $j=0;

     $p1=$str1[i];
     $p2=$str2[j]; 
  while(true)
   {  
       if(ord($p1)<ord($p2)||($p1==''&&$p2==''))
         {

           return($str1);
         }
      else
         {
           if(ord($p1)==ord($p2))
             {
              $p1=$str1[++$i];
              $p2=$str2[++$j];
              continue;
             }
          return($str2); 
         }
   }//end while

  } //end function find string order

 public function is_empty()
  {
    if($this->root==null)
      return(true);
    else
      return(false);
  }
}//end class BinaryTree
?>
```